# Liferay: Facelet portlet is empty

Tags: jsf, liferay

I have developed a simple facelet portlet. Changed the ViewHandler in the `faces-config.xml` as it is said in the book:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE faces-config PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JavaServer Faces Config
1.1//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-facesconfig_1_1.dtd">
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/JSF/Configuration">
 <application>
   <view-handler>
       com.sun.facelets.FaceletPortletViewHandler
   </view-handler>
 </application>
<factory>
    <faces-context-
        factory>com.liferay.util.bridges.jsf.myfaces.MyFacesContextFactoryImpl</faces-
        context-factory>
</factory>
</faces-config>
```

There are 2 `.xhtml` pages: template.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h:outputText value="block"></h:outputText>
        <h:outputLabel value="label" for="input"/>
        <h:inputText id="input"/>
        JUST TEXT
        <ui:insert name="insertBlock">
            <h:outputText value="defaultText"></h:outputText>
        </ui:insert>
    </body>
</html>
```

and insertedBlock.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ui:composition template="template.xhtml"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
  <ui:define name="insertBlock">
    <h:outputText value="Inderted block"/>
    <h:outputLabel value="test label" for="testInput"/>
    <h:inputText id="testInput"/>
  </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

portlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<portlet-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd">
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>LiferayFirstPortlet_war_exploded</portlet-name>
    <display-name>LiferayFirstPortlet_war_exploded</display-name>
    <portlet-class>com.test.HelloWorld</portlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <name>default-view</name>
        <value>insertedBlock.xhtml</value>
    </init-param>
    <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>
    <supports>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
    </supports>
    <portlet-info>
        <title>LiferayFirstPortlet_war_exploded</title>
    </portlet-info>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>administrator</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>guest</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>power-user</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
</portlet>
 </portlet-app>
```

When I deploy this portlet on the Liferay - no errors are displayed. But when I add the portlet on a page IT IS EMPTY - just the empty rectangle. The code of the page (html code inspection in the fireBug) shown that there is no content in the portlet either.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you include liferay specific artifacts? For a porlet to be deployed in liferay, the artifact needs some liferay specific configuration files. You can create a skeletal artifact using the Liferay Plugin SDK. (You can find it in, additional files download section.)

Or you can download the [JSF samples](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Sample+Portlets#section-Sample+Portlets-JSFTechnologies) and alter it to match your configuration.

Comment: By the way, what book are you talking about??

Comment: Yes, I've added liferay-display.xml and liferay-portlet.xml. And when I have tried them for the pure JSF (without facelets) everything worked ok.

Comment: The book is "JavaServer Faces 2.0. The Complete Reference."

Comment: Did the Jsf portlet without Facelets work? Just check the libs that you have packaged and compare them to the libs in the sample project..

Comment: Yes. I have done this. No changes... Can somebody, please, try to deploy my portlet?

Comment: Are all: jsf & facelets of the latest versions? Combining several tutorials and searching the libraries by these values may lead in conflicts of versions.